# invisible navbar in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My navbar goes from transparent to no transparent when scrolling.

I am doing a I am trying to do something similar like this. Here is the [link](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/creative/):

[image: invisible_navbar]

My navbar looks at the beginning like this:

[image: my_nav]

I can see that it has a light border and the font is not white. But I want to be like in the example I showed above. Can you please help me to do it?

Here is my code so far:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top shadow-lg">
  <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
          </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
          aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link p-2 text-dark" href="/">Lorem <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link p-2 text-dark" href="/uns">Lorem <span
                          class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle p-2 text-dark" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                      role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Produkte
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#winkelstufe">Lorem</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#auftritt">Lorem</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#volltritt">Lorem</a>
                  </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link p-2 text-dark" href="/galerie">Lorem</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link p-2 text-dark" href="/jobs">Lorem</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link p-2 text-dark" href="#contact2">Lorem</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

my css:

```
nav.navbar{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.navbar-inverse {
   /* background-color: #222;
   border-color: #080808; */
}

nav.navbar.transparent {
 background-color:white;
}

.navbar {
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

my js:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $('nav').addClass('transparent');
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('transparent');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `shadow-lg` from the navbar, you just need the class to be applied after you scroll; having that declared inline will apply the shadow all the time.

Take note of the text color as well; you have `navbar-dark` on your nav, this causes the text to be white; just make sure to change this style when you add the `.transparent` class.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('transparent');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('transparent');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey !important;
}

nav.navbar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.nav-item .nav-link {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  /* background-color: #222;
   border-color: #080808; */
}

nav.navbar.transparent {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #000;
}

nav.navbar.transparent .nav-link {
  color: black;
}

.navbar {
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-expand fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link p-2" href="/">Lorem <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link p-2" href="/uns">Lorem <span
                          class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle p-2" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Produkte
                  </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#winkelstufe">Lorem</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#auftritt">Lorem</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#volltritt">Lorem</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link p-2" href="/galerie">Lorem</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link p-2" href="/jobs">Lorem</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link p-2" href="#contact2">Lorem</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<p class="mt-5">
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores illum provident iure doloribus autem veniam aperiam nam atque iste quia, magni sapiente, sunt, culpa minima et nostrum dolor eveniet? Saepe velit corporis quaerat laudantium esse cumque
  nobis in. Dolores accusamus laudantium non neque veniam cupiditate labore corrupti voluptatibus quo cumque repellendus fugit doloribus, recusandae maiores accusantium omnis aut tempore. Reprehenderit neque officiis deleniti laudantium reiciendis recusandae,
  adipisci, dolores officia at dolorem a. Non consectetur alias velit modi aspernatur voluptatem nesciunt optio enim. Reiciendis nemo odio, commodi eos iure minima ullam nulla dicta dolorum aspernatur. Iusto animi quasi molestias? Repellendus, illum,
  amet, aliquam suscipit dolor voluptates facilis libero odio hic eos neque magni esse soluta quam adipisci. Eligendi explicabo similique recusandae ipsum praesentium excepturi enim, placeat eum libero! Tempore labore officia optio accusantium fugiat
  voluptate maxime expedita, dolores perferendis eos numquam delectus at odit cupiditate atque corporis rem reprehenderit consequatur velit.</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores illum provident iure doloribus autem veniam aperiam nam atque iste quia, magni sapiente, sunt, culpa minima et nostrum dolor eveniet? Saepe velit corporis quaerat laudantium esse cumque
  nobis in. Dolores accusamus laudantium non neque veniam cupiditate labore corrupti voluptatibus quo cumque repellendus fugit doloribus, recusandae maiores accusantium omnis aut tempore. Reprehenderit neque officiis deleniti laudantium reiciendis recusandae,
  adipisci, dolores officia at dolorem a. Non consectetur alias velit modi aspernatur voluptatem nesciunt optio enim. Reiciendis nemo odio, commodi eos iure minima ullam nulla dicta dolorum aspernatur. Iusto animi quasi molestias? Repellendus, illum,
  amet, aliquam suscipit dolor voluptates facilis libero odio hic eos neque magni esse soluta quam adipisci. Eligendi explicabo similique recusandae ipsum praesentium excepturi enim, placeat eum libero! Tempore labore officia optio accusantium fugiat
  voluptate maxime expedita, dolores perferendis eos numquam delectus at odit cupiditate atque corporis rem reprehenderit consequatur velit.</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores illum provident iure doloribus autem veniam aperiam nam atque iste quia, magni sapiente, sunt, culpa minima et nostrum dolor eveniet? Saepe velit corporis quaerat laudantium esse cumque
  nobis in. Dolores accusamus laudantium non neque veniam cupiditate labore corrupti voluptatibus quo cumque repellendus fugit doloribus, recusandae maiores accusantium omnis aut tempore. Reprehenderit neque officiis deleniti laudantium reiciendis recusandae,
  adipisci, dolores officia at dolorem a. Non consectetur alias velit modi aspernatur voluptatem nesciunt optio enim. Reiciendis nemo odio, commodi eos iure minima ullam nulla dicta dolorum aspernatur. Iusto animi quasi molestias? Repellendus, illum,
  amet, aliquam suscipit dolor voluptates facilis libero odio hic eos neque magni esse soluta quam adipisci. Eligendi explicabo similique recusandae ipsum praesentium excepturi enim, placeat eum libero! Tempore labore officia optio accusantium fugiat
  voluptate maxime expedita, dolores perferendis eos numquam delectus at odit cupiditate atque corporis rem reprehenderit consequatur velit.</p>
```

Comment: thx! it worked. But at the beginning before going no transparent, the content of the navbar is black. Can you help me to make it white

Comment: How so? In the example above it the text is white due to the `navbar-dark` class, are you using the same class?

Comment: Yes, just saw it that I have ```navbar-dark``` so I made it ```navbar-white```. How can I make the navbar again dark when it goes again to no transparent by scrolling

Comment: There's no `navbar-white` class in Bootstrap so that is not necessary... You can toggle the class `navbar-dark` on the same function when you scroll, or add more styles on your CSS, I'll edit the answer

Comment: @Behar just edited the answer; you can see I added some styles to the `.nav-link` so they are white by default and black when the `.transparent` class is added

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I am looking for!